# Is it possible to generate both HTML and Wiki markup at the same time using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I would like to generate both HTML and Wiki markup at the same time using XSLT (from an XML source document) - just wondering if it's possible. It would be nice if I could use the same XSLT to do both rather than writing/maintaining two separate files.

The HTML report will be for general viewing, and the Wiki markup will be published to Confluence.

Comment: Using XSLT 2.0 and `xsl:result-document` or using XSLT 1.0 and a processor specific extension a single XSLT stylesheet can create more than one result document. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That appears to be it, thank you...

Comment: I have extended the comment into an answer so that you can mark your question as being solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create more than one result document using a single stylesheet than XSLT 2.0 and later support that using `xsl:result-document`, see the specification http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees. As you then want to process the same elements twice, you usually also make use of modes to separate the different processing, e.g. use one mode to produce HTML, the other mode to produce Wiki markup.

With pure XSLT 1.0 you can only create a single result document, however, some XSLT 1.0 processors, like Xalan (http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions_xsltc.html#redirect_ext) or xsltproc (http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html) support an extension to create more than one result document.